# get picklist values from object field to LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, picklist, custom-field

Hello everybody I am trying to pass picklist values from object field to other picklist input fields in LWC without using the recordTypeId because in my case the object does not have a recordType.

I have seen in sites like this:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_picklist_values

Is there an alternative by using only the object api name and the field api name?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `recordTypeId` of `012000000000000AAA` is the "null" Record Type Id. You use this value if your object doesn't have record types, or if you want to use the main/master Record Type Id. The example in the documentation is a literal example you can copy-paste into any org.

Comment: Hello I tried this approach... it worked perfectly in my scratch org but in the production org does not work. Do you have any idea how to solve this? I thought it was going to work perfectly.

Comment: @TechGuy It should work correctly in any org; that's the point of the null ID. I suggest you post a new question that includes your specific problem, the code, and any error messages you may have, we'll be happy to help you out.